# How can I compile XJig for Snow Leopard?

Tags: c++, xcode, osx-snow-leopard

I'm trying to compile XJig (http://sourceforge.net/projects/xjig/) for Snow Leopard and getting errors:

```
make
c++ -m32 -DUSE_MIT_SHM  -DJIG_DEFAULT=\"/usr/lib/games/xjig/tina.gif\" -c xjig.C -o                                                         
xjig.o
xjig.C:161: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
xjig.C: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
xjig.C:527: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
xjig.C:527: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
xjig.C:527: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
xjig.C:720: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
c++ -m32 -DUSE_MIT_SHM    -c -o objects.o objects.C
c++ -m32 -DUSE_MIT_SHM    -c -o stack.o stack.C
c++ -m32 -DUSE_MIT_SHM    -c -o imgbuff.o imgbuff.C
c++ -m32 -DUSE_MIT_SHM    -c -o puzzle.o puzzle.C
c++ -m32 -DUSE_MIT_SHM    -c -o real.o real.C
c++ -m32 -DUSE_MIT_SHM    -c -o vec2.o vec2.C
c++ -m32 -DUSE_MIT_SHM    -c -o vec2list.o vec2list.C
c++ -m32 -DUSE_MIT_SHM    -c -o mat2.o mat2.C
c++ -m32 -DUSE_MIT_SHM    -c -o color_mapper.o color_mapper.C
c++ -m32 -DUSE_MIT_SHM    -c -o base_image.o base_image.C
c++ -m32 -DUSE_MIT_SHM    -c -o gif_image.o gif_image.C
c++ -m32 -DUSE_MIT_SHM    -c -o ximage.o ximage.C
c++ -m32 -DUSE_MIT_SHM    -c -o ppm_image.o ppm_image.C
In file included from ppm_image.C:6:
/usr/local/include/ppmcmap.h:110: 
error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
make: *** [ppm_image.o] Error 1
```

It is complaining about the extern 'C' includes at the top of header files but my understanding is that a c++ compilers should understand this.

Should I be making a project in Xcode and compiling it in there? I have very little knowledge in compiling C source code but would like to get this working.

### Update

The source was updated to 2.5.4 and fixes the error but I'm now getting:

```
make
c++ -m32 -DUSE_MIT_SHM  -DJIG_DEFAULT=\"/usr/lib/games/xjig/tina.gif\" -c xjig.C -o xjig.o
c++ -m32 -DUSE_MIT_SHM    -c -o objects.o objects.C
c++ -m32 -DUSE_MIT_SHM    -c -o stack.o stack.C
c++ -m32 -DUSE_MIT_SHM    -c -o imgbuff.o imgbuff.C
c++ -m32 -DUSE_MIT_SHM    -c -o puzzle.o puzzle.C
c++ -m32 -DUSE_MIT_SHM    -c -o real.o real.C
c++ -m32 -DUSE_MIT_SHM    -c -o vec2.o vec2.C
c++ -m32 -DUSE_MIT_SHM    -c -o vec2list.o vec2list.C
c++ -m32 -DUSE_MIT_SHM    -c -o mat2.o mat2.C
c++ -m32 -DUSE_MIT_SHM    -c -o color_mapper.o color_mapper.C
c++ -m32 -DUSE_MIT_SHM    -c -o base_image.o base_image.C
c++ -m32 -DUSE_MIT_SHM    -c -o gif_image.o gif_image.C
c++ -m32 -DUSE_MIT_SHM    -c -o ximage.o ximage.C
c++ -m32 -DUSE_MIT_SHM    -c -o jpeg_image.o jpeg_image.C
rm -f xjig
c++ -m32 -o xjig xjig.o objects.o stack.o imgbuff.o puzzle.o                       real.o vec2.o vec2list.o mat2.o                       color_mapper.o base_image.o gif_image.o ximage.o                      jpeg_image.o -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing       -lXext -lX11 -ljpeg -lnetpbm -lm     
ld: library not found for -lXext
```

Comment: Which version of xjig as http://sourceforge.net/projects/xjig/develop implies 2-5.3 has this error

Comment: good spot - somebody fixed it 2 hours ago. But I'm now getting another error - I'll update the question

Comment: -lXext is not going to work on Snow Leopard so I think I will need to create a new makefile and / or compile in XCode. Problem is I have no idea how. Anyone know a good resource for learning this? I find the apple documentation very terse as it assumes a level of knowledge I don't have.

Comment: Just try editing the makefile to remove -lXext - might work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'somebody' who fixed it was me. I rushed a fixed after your first posting.
Go and download again.(2.5.4-1) I missed a couple of references to the old ppm stuff, the errors only showed on a fresh build. It should compile ok now.

If you still have problems, contact me directly.

**About the make file.**
The make file is created by imake on the initial build.

You can use the supplied make files with most versions of **Linux**, but you should use the imake file by doing:  xmkmf, make depend, make.

**Just a note about the Makefile.**

You should **not** edit the Makefile.

Use imake (xmkmf)

Imake is a tool for configuring the X Window System and its components for different platforms. It came with your X11 installation. The command for imake is **xmkmf.**

When you run 'xmkmf', it looks for a file called 'Imakefile' in the current directory, and makes a 'Makefile'.

So, to create a makefile for your system, you edit the Imakefile, and then run **xmkmf** in the xjig source folder.

Then do '**make depend**', '**make**', '**sudo make install**'.

Update to my last post.

I do not have a mac, so I borrowed a mac with tiger on it to test with.

After making a couple of changes to the Imakefile, I successfully compiled xjig and installed it, and it runs ok.

The latest version is now 2.5.4-2, and I have uploaded it to xjigmanager.com and sourceforge.net/projects/xjig/

The downside is that because xjigmanager runs in gambas, which cannot run on the mac, you have to use xjig in xterm.